# Why is Resharper telling me my string[] is never assigned?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

On this declaration:

```
string[] TardyEvenEmorys;
```

...Resharper tells me, "*Field 'TardyEvenEmorys' is never assigned.*"

Later on in the code, assignments are made to the string[]:

```
TardyEvenEmorys[1] = string.Empty;
TardyEvenEmorys[2] = string.Empty;
TardyEvenEmorys[3] = string.Empty;
TardyEvenEmorys[4] = string.Empty;
```

...and then actual values are conditionally added:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> entry in itemNumberTardyPairs)
{
    TardyEvenEmorys[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
```

. . .

...finally, those values are used in this way:

```
string url = GetTardyFilename(TardyEvenEmorys[Number]);
```

So what is Resharper telling me? That I should instantiate the string[] on declaration, or...???

Comment: At what point do you define the length of the array?

Comment: If you had tried to run the code, you would have found out the reason instantly.

Comment: I have run the code; it compiles fine; only Resharper complains.

Comment: Running and compiling are not the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're assigning individual elements of the array, but never actually creating the *array itself*.

> So what is Resharper telling me? That I should instantiate the string[] on declaration, or...???

You need to instantiate the array somewhere.  This could be during the declaration, or later.  For example, to do it during the declaration, you would need to add:

```
string[] TardyEvenEmorys = new string[5]; // Some appropriate length
```

Without this, the first time you assign one of the elements, you'll get an exception since the array is null.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just picked 5 because he's showing assignments up to 4, so 5 covers that ;)  No idea how many are actually needed for the second set of code, though

Answer (score 3):

You are missing following code somewhere and should be getting null pointer exception:

```
TardyEvenEmorys = new string[22];
```